# Why I am gettiing an error while calling a function over decorator

Tags: python, decorator

Could some please explain me whey I am getting an error along with correct output using python 2.7.

```
def func1(func):
    def func2():
        print("Before func2")
        func()
        print("After func2")
    return func2()

@func1
def func_d():
    print("I am being decorated")

func_d()
```

output is:

```
Before func2
I am being decorated
After func2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "s.py", line 48, in <module>
func_d()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the function object from your decorator function, and not actually call the function and return its returning value.

Change:

```
return func2()
```

to:

```
return func2
```